# Geoserver output is too small also in WMS

Tags: qgis, wms, zoom

I encountered a problem in geoserver. My shapefile output is very small even when I output in my WMS using GeoExt tree-legend.

Here is my Layer Preview in Geoserver:

[image]

This is my code in GeoExt tree-legend:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Tree Legend',
    launch: function() {
        var mapPanel = Ext.create('GeoExt.MapPanel', {
            region: "center",
            center: [280858.84899, 1594924.75501],
            zoom: 10,
            layers: [
                new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("TALABA IV",
                    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Bacoor/wms",
                    {
                        layers: 'talaba iv',
                        format: 'image/png',
                        transparent: false
                    },
                    {   
                        //displayInLayerSwitcher: true,
                        //isBaseLayer: true,
                        //transitionEffect: 'resize'
                        //singleTile: true
                    }
                ),
            ]
        });
```

Comment: thank you for the edit @TomazicM

Comment: What is the coordinate system of your source data? Have a look at the bounding boxes on the layer page of your GeoServer admin utility. Do numbers make sense?

Comment: thats kinda my problem.. in my geoserver when it calls for my layer it says 4326 in the command line thing but I uploaded my layer in geoserver as EPSG: 3123. In my bounding boxes i just click compute from srs bounds. here it is : Min X: 355,474.8861579494 Min Y: 331,688.22444229515 Max X: 634,517.9840100077 Max Y: 2,392,026.521460461

Comment: Hi again. i was able to get the extent by changing the crs to 3857 in my geoserver but my problem is still with my web application it is still too small and needs to be zoomed before it appears.